# Draw Pascal's triangle in PASCAL Programming like a diamond

Tags: pascal, pascals-triangle

How I can draw a Pascal's triangle in PASCAL Programming like a diamond from n number which we get that from input?

**Edit:**
This program I tried:

```
program Pascal_triangle;
var
i,j,n : integer;
A : Array[1..6,1..6] of Integer;
begin
   n := 6;
   for i:=1 to n do
   begin
      for j:=1 to i do
      begin
         if (j=1) or (i=j) then
         begin
            A[i,j]:=1;
         end
         else
         begin
            A[i,j] := A[i-1,j] + A[i-1,j-1];
         end;
      end;
   end;
   for i:=1 to n do
   begin
      Gotoxy(41-i,i);
      for j:=1 to i do
         write(A[i,j])
   end;
   readln;
end.
```

but I got an error on gotoxy line and I need it to be diamond.

Comment: fix your code indentation, the code is unreadable like this...

Comment: see last edit I added the program I tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Dec 31 '11 at 21:22:** Thanks, I wrote this and works

```
program Pascal_triangle;
var d,c,y,x,n : integer;
   begin
      readln(n);
      writeln;
      for y:=0 to n do
      begin
         c:=1;
         for d:=0 to n - y do
         begin
            write(' ');
         end;
         for x:=0 to y do
         begin
            write(c);
            write(' ');
            c := c * (y - x) DIV (x + 1);
         end;
         writeln;
      end;
      for y:=n-1 downto 0 do
      begin
         c:=1;
         for d:=0 to n - y do
         begin
            write(' ');
         end;
         for x:=0 to y do
         begin
            write(c);
            write(' ');
            c := c * (y - x) DIV (x + 1);
         end;
         writeln;
      end;
      readln;
   end.
```